# Case-insensitive statements?

Tags: php

Please forgive the ignorance, but I'm very new to PHP and I couldn't find what I want out there anywhere. So I've com here, where I know I'll get an answer.

What I want to do is accommodate for any letter case inconsistencies in the data I am pulling in (which I didn't create).

For example I would like the following if statement to work even if the $var is written as 'hello', 'HELLO', 'Hello', 'HeLlo', 'hELLo', 'hElLo',.. etc etc.

```
if ($var == 'hello') {
 echo 'It works!';
}
```

Obviously that won't, but what could I do to that to make it not worry about the case of the text?

I have had a look around for these kinds of things, I found `strcasecmp()`, but to me that doesn't seem to be exactly what I want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why don't you try:

```
if (strtolower($var) == 'hello') {
 echo 'It works!';
}
```

So if `$var = 'HelLo';`, it will put it to lower case

Comment: how about `if(e == strtolower(É))` ?? If your content is UTF-8 you'll better use `mb_strtolower($string, 'UTF-8')`. Take a look http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strtolower.php

Comment: I don't know what's going on but that's not doing anything. Nothing is. What have I done wrong here?
`$var == 'HEllO';
if (strtolower($var) == 'hello') {
 echo 'It works!';
}`

Even this won't work:
`echo $var;`

Have a look for yourself - http://getfilm.co.uk/case-insensitivity.php

Comment: look at the demo here: http://codepad.org/PgiFEf9z    set `$var` with only **ONE** equals sign: `$var = 'HEllO'`

Answer (score 1):

Use strtolower

eg:

```
$var = 'HeLLo';
if (strtolower($var) == 'hello') {
 echo "it works";
}
```

Comment: hehe :-p. thats all i have to say

Answer (score 1):

There's a dedicated PHP function for this - `strcasecmp($str1, $str2)`. However, I would still go with the strtolower($var) because you don't have to worry about unicode.